# False value from User Input

Tags: c#, .net, console.readline

I am trying to save the value i get through Console.Read() in an Integer, but whatever i type in my keyboard, the console always gives out 13. I tried to copy an example code, which definitly has to work, but im still only getting 13 as value.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Read();
            int Test = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(Test);
        }
    }
}
```

After i typed in a number, it always shows '13' in the console.

Comment: 13 - is a key code of _enter_. You want to use [Console.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2):

[`Console.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.8) reads first character from input stream.

In your case, You are trying to convert second character of input stream(i.e.after first `Console.Read()`) which is `Carriage return` and its ASCII value is 13, `Test` variable which is of type `int`, storing `carriage return` in integer format. i.e `13`

If you want to convert first character from input stream, then try below

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Test = Console.Read();  //Or you can use Console.ReadLine() to read entire line.
            Console.WriteLine(Test);//Print first character of input stream
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked with Console.ReadLine(), this is really confusing but i understand it now :)

Comment: @DominicTeut If it helped and you think this answer is helpful and informative than other then accept it by green tick.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have to use Console.ReadLine to read the number. As Console.ReadLine returns string, you have to convert it to Int32. The following code will fix the issue

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             int Test = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(Test);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this to:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Test = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Test);
        }
    }
}
```

Since 13 is key code for enter, you are probably getting that number from trying to read the whole line.